# How to hide column border of grid in WPF?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf

I have following grid. I have to hide column border of the grid and change the color of the row border. How to do that in WPF?[image]

Also I have to make padding between the cells contents.

Comment: How is this relevant to asp.net?  And how are you displaying your grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid lines are pretty straightforward: use HorizontalGridLinesBrush and VerticalGridLinesBrush properties of the DataGrid.
For red horizontal lines and transparent vertical lines:

```
    <DataGrid HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Red" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"/>
```

Padding is not that obvious: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5247078/786055

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `GridLinesVisibility="None"`

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None">
    ...
<DataGrid>
```