# WPF datagrid header/data align issues

Tags: wpf, datagrid, header, alignment

There is a WPF Datagrid, with nothing special with it. It has sometimes HeadersVisibility All/Row, depends on the usage in our code.
But regardless of the header style, it has alignment issues.
Neither the header/data text are aligned properly, nor the first headers in the top-left corner, 1 pixel is missing here.
I attach a picture to be more visible.

[image]

This really looks unprofessional and amateur.
The text align is much worse than the top-left corner, so if I could fix that it would already be a big improvement.

Vertical: as I see, the row header texts are aligned properly to the center, unlike the data which is a bit above.

Horizontal: here does not matter which one is aligned to which (header<>data), but at least they should be in-line.

Thanks

**EDIT**
The XAML part:

```
<dg2d:DataGrid2DT.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="wpftoolkit:DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</dg2d:DataGrid2DT.CellStyle>
```

I tried to add `<Setter Property="TextBlock.Padding" Value="5, 5, 0, 0" />` but this had no effect. Just for try I added `<Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />` - this works fine. Only paddig does nothing. Maybe cell is too small for padding?

**EDIT2**

If I set VerticalAlignment to "Center" Textblock is put to the center of the cell. With this the text is more or less in the center, but not good, as textblock is not filling the cell anymore. I want the textblock to fill the cell, and have the text vertically centered.
Using "Padding" should solve my problem, but it has no effect.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set the `VerticalAlingment` and/or 'HorizontalAlignment' of the content-control of your rowheader or column-header. You can also try to set them on your Cell

Comment: But the alignment issue is not with the row or column header, but with the data cell. See the screenshot, header text is well-aligned, unlike the data cell.

Comment: How do you define the cell? as `DataGridTemplateColumn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, by using `Padding` I can align the cell text to be inline with the header texts.
However, as I mentioned, using simple `Padding`  or `TextBlock.Padding` does not work, you need a "trick", I found it here:
[Set a padding on dataGridCells in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246745/set-a-padding-on-datagridcells-in-wpf)

```
<dg2d:DataGrid2DT.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="wpftoolkit:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>

--> solution
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,2,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type wpftoolkit:DataGridCell}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
<-- solution

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</dg2d:DataGrid2DT.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center the text in your `DataGridColumn` like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="1">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item1Property}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Cells are not defined in the XAML. I think they are generated dynamically in the code. (sorry, this is not my code, I am just taking over, and I am not familiar with wpf)

Comment: I have this in the XAML which contains DataTemplate:
`<dg2d:DataGrid2DT.RowHeaderTemplate>`
`<DataTemplate>`
`<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpftoolkit:DataGridRow}},Path=Header}"/>`
`</DataTemplate>`
`</dg2d:DataGrid2DT.RowHeaderTemplate>`

Comment: In the xaml I only see a `DataTemplate` for the RowHeader and not for a  spezific column. I thought the columns are your problem???

Comment: My problem is that cell text is neither vertically aligned with the row header text, nor horizontally with the column header text. See the image above, and see the red lines are not continuous.

Comment: There is also an event handler of `AutoGeneratingColumn` , here the `column.Binding.Path` is set.

Comment: Edited the question...see the end