# WPF textblock, padding has no effect

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grid, padding, textblock

I have a grid, where cells contain textblock.
I want to add some padding to the text in the cells (to move them inline with the header texts), but it has no effect.

XAML:

```
<dg2d:DataGrid2DT.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="wpftoolkit:DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Padding" Value="4, 4, 4, 4" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</dg2d:DataGrid2DT.CellStyle>
```

Whatever I set in the padding, it's always the same, see:

[image]

Why `Padding` does not work here?

## EDIT: Thanks to Muds, the SOLUTION:

[Set a padding on dataGridCells in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246745/set-a-padding-on-datagridcells-in-wpf)

Comment: are you sure you need padding here and not margin ?

Comment: Have you tried `Padding` instead of `TextBlock.Padding`?

Comment: @Muds, no margin will make space outside of the control, see: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2ylaiis.jpg

Comment: @MikeEason: using `Padding` has also no any effect.

Comment: read this - [similar example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246745/set-a-padding-on-datagridcells-in-wpf)

Comment: @Muds, thank you, indeed that's a good help, I could SOLVE my issue with this, thanks!